# Eclipse plugin: How to show a ProcessConsole for a launch with a custom launch configuration and process?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a custom launch configuration, implementing `ILaunchConfigurationDelegate`. I create a new `IProcess` via `DebugPlugin.newProcess`. I have a custom process factory, too, so I get an instance of my custom `IProcess`. I then write to the process's output stream monitor:

```
public class MyLauncher implements ILaunchConfigurationDelegate {
    @Override
    public void launch(ILaunchConfiguration configuration, String mode, ILaunch launch, IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException {
        if (monitor == null) monitor = new NullProgressMonitor();

        // launch a new process
        MyProcess process = DebugPlugin.newProcess(launch, null, configuration.getName()).getAdapter(MyProcess.class);
        if (process == null) {
            // ERROR
            throw new CoreException(new Status(Status.ERROR, MyPlugin.ID, "Process factory not configured correctly in the launch configuration"));
        }

        process.out.append("Hello, World!\n");

        process.terminate();
    }
}
```

This all works fine, but one thing does not occur: A console doesn't appear. I can make a custom console appear like this:

```
MyConsole console = /*code to make a custom console here*/;
console.activate();
ConsolePlugin.getDefault().getConsoleManager().addConsoles(new IConsole[] {console});
```

But this isn't a `ProcessConsole`, which is what the Launch API should be providing me. It's not doing it automatically, and it's standard procedure for launches to use such a console, so I know I have to get one to show up somehow. It's marked as internal, so I shouldn't be making one manually, I don't think. Furthermore, `DebugUITools.getConsole` always returns `null`.

I have a feeling this is because I'm forgetting to do something in my custom `IProcess`:

```
public class MyProcess implements IProcess {
    private ILaunch launch;
    private String label;
    private IStreamsProxy proxy;
    private Map<String, String> attributes;
    private boolean terminated;
    public MyOutputStream out;

    public MyProcess(ILaunch launch, String label, Map<String, String> attributes) {
        this.launch = launch;
        this.label = label;
        this.attributes = attributes;

        out = new MyOutputStream();

        proxy = new IStreamsProxy() {
            @Override
            public void write(String input) throws IOException {

            }

            @Override
            public IStreamMonitor getOutputStreamMonitor() {
                return out;
            }

            @Override
            public IStreamMonitor getErrorStreamMonitor() {
                return out;
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T getAdapter(Class<T> adapter) {
        if (adapter.equals(MyProcess.class)) {
            return (T) this;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canTerminate() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isTerminated() {
        return terminated;
    }

    @Override
    public void terminate() throws DebugException {
        launch.terminate();
        terminated = true;
    }

    @Override
    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    @Override
    public ILaunch getLaunch() {
        return launch;
    }

    @Override
    public IStreamsProxy getStreamsProxy() {
        return proxy;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAttribute(String key, String value) {
        attributes.put(key, value);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAttribute(String key) {
        return attributes.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public int getExitValue() throws DebugException {
        return 0;
    }
}

public class MyOutputStream implements IStreamMonitor {
    private String contents = "";
    private List<IStreamListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void addListener(IStreamListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public String getContents() {
        return contents;
    }

    @Override
    public void removeListener(IStreamListener listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    public void append(Object o) {
        contents += o;
        listeners.stream().forEach((l)->l.streamAppended(String.valueOf(o), this));
    }
}
```

So, in short, how do I get a `ProcessConsole` to appear? Is it even possible to do this when you use a nonstandard `IProcess`?

Comment: The only place ProcessConsole is created is in `org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.views.console.ProcessConsoleManager` which uses a `ILauchListener`

Comment: `ProcessConsoleMa‌​nager`, unfortunately, is only obtained through `DebugUIPlugin.getProcessConsoleManager`, which is also marked as internal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the correct functionality for your process, you shouldn't implement `IProcess` directly; you should extend `RuntimeProcess` instead. It has all the methods you need to properly activate the console view.

However, if you wish to implement `IProcess` directly, there are some things you need to do:

- Add `getLaunch().addProcess(this);` to the end of your constructor
- Fire `DebugEvent`s in the correct locations (on creation, termination, and the change of an attribute)
- Implement `getAdapter` to adapt on receiving an `IProcess`, `IDebugTarget`, `ILaunch`, and `ILaunchConfiguration`

If you do all these things, you'll get the `ProcessConsole` to appear when you start up your `IProcess`.